# Django App - Server error when accessing tables in Admin

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

So I've had a live application running for 8 months now. This app is used for exchanging textbooks between students.

The relevant db tables are textbooks, postings, wishlists, users, and log entries. I use facebook login and each time a user logs in they get an ID which has been incremented by one up until 465 but the most recent user got id 498 for some reason. Also, this user added some textbooks so log entries were created. The Id's for these log entries all shot up instead of being incremented.

So, one I am confused about why this happened and two when I try to access the posting and wishlist tables I get a server error. Both these tables have foreign keys to user and textbooks. The textbooks table is accessible however. This is all on the admin page.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: What are the errors? What is the code responsible for IDs? Is there anything else you think might be relevant?

Comment: Well I am just looking at it in production right now and I get my server error 500 page. I believe the ID code is part of the facebook login code.

Comment: I know I could view all the tables before that weird ID popped up. I am hosting my database on heroku. Could it fill up and overlap? Or something like that?

Comment: Check server logs for cause of error 500 and add it to your question. Also, what app takes care of FB login? Can you see the database if there are empty rows or something else that isn't alright?